# ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1 Docker compose error

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pip

```
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install numpy
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "7272"]
```

At first I thought that pip might not work, I decided to try to upgrade it using the command RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
Pip updated and could install libraries individually

Here you can see my requirements.txt:

```
torch==2.0.0
torchaudio==2.0.0
torchnet==0.0.4
torchvision==0.15.0
tornado==6.2
tqdm==4.62.3
uvicorn==0.22.0
fastapi==0.95.1
```

Comment: Usually, issue comes from incorrect library spelling, version or library downloading issue. check for docker logs will help in this case.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] along with the output it produces.

Comment: You need to provide more details on the error that's occurring.